# What is the "opposite" of a random variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, definition

I am learning about random variables with all of their different types of distributions for discrete and continuous types. However, before knowing about random variables, I am not sure what would be a variable in statistics which is not random? Is not every variable by chance and everything already a random variable? What would be the "opposite" of a random variable i.e. some variable which is NOT to happen by chance?

Comment: what is the context of this question? Maybe you can write a sentence and leave ___ blank where you wanna use the concept you are looking for?

Comment: Just to be clear, the term "random variable" in this context is to be considered as a single term, not a composed term "random" + "variable". Thus, it makes no sense to ask what a "non-random" + "variable" is...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A random variable which is not actually random, and doesn't change by chance, is by definition a *constant*. But, it is still a [RV](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Degenerate_distribution#/Constant_random_variable). Since the RV definition is a superset of constant RV definition, I believe there is no conceptual *opposite*.

Comment: Okay. So when you flip a coin, is the probability of it landing on heads $0.5$ a constant or can it also be defined with a random variable?

Comment: It doesn't have to be constant, and can be modeled as random. But even if it is constant, it's still a RV by definition. How you model your variables usually depends on you.

Comment: For the coin flip, you'd say the outcome is a V~Bernoulli(P) where V (in {Heads, Tails}) is a Bernoulli random variable with a constant parameter P=0.5.  (As @gunes mentions, a constant is technically an RV will all its probability mass concentrated at a single point).  Sometimes, like for example if you don't know if the coin is biased or not, you might even treat P (in [0, 1]) as an RV.  Typical textbook problem is to compute the distribution over P given the evidence of seeing the outcomes of N coin-flips.

Comment: -1 A *variable* which is both deterministic and non-constant is not a random variable. For example, $x_{1}=1,x_{2}=2,\dots,x_{n}=n$ is a trivial non-random variable. A constant is, by definition, non-*variable*.

Comment: @Alexis, I appreciate the comment. I also think that it's misleading to refer it as just *variable*. Reworded.

Comment: Your revision still neglects that variables can be non-random without being constant. Another example: $x_1 = 1, x_{2} = 0, x_{3} = 1, \dots$ (i.e. $x$ is an indicator variable for the oddness of the index).

Comment: @Alexis right they can be non random and still non-constant, but my answer isn’t about *variable*s, it is about RVs. I refrain from using the term variable on its own.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that might be worth noting is that in the formal definition, a random variable is a **function** -- in particular, a measurable function  $X: \Omega \to E$ from a set of possible outcomes $\Omega$ (which is in fact a probability space -- more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition)) to a measurable space $E$.

Along the same lines of @gunes answer (+1), it doesn't quite make sense to discuss the opposite of a function -- you could say it's a constant, but how would you consider a function such as $f(x) = 0$? Is it "more" constant than other functions? It's a bit like comparing apples and oranges, since functions and scalars are very different types of objects.

I think your question is more around the use of the word "variable", which can be a bit confusing. For instance, in algebra you might encounter a problem such as "*Find the roots of the equation $x^2-9=0$*". Here, $x$ is a "variable", but it takes on a deterministic value (namely, $ x = \pm 3$ ) and can really be considered scalar since $x \in {\Bbb R}$. There's no presumption of it representing a relationship between some event and an associated probability, so it's not considered a random variable.

Answer (score 4):

A non-random variable is generally called a Constant.  But constants are not really the opposite of random variables, in the same way integers are not the opposite of real numbers - they're a subset.

A constant is just a random variable with all it's probability mass concentrated at one point.  (i.e. it has a [Dirac-delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for probability distribution)

Answer (score 1):

I would say a deterministic variable.

Examples:

Random variable- the amount of heads when a coin is tossed 100 times.
Deterministic variable- the age of the Eifel tower in exactly 12 years from now.

Comment: This perhaps is not a good analogy: who can be 100% sure the Eiffel tower will even exist in 12 years?